# activerecord belongs_to refactoring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, refactoring

I have many belongs_to relations

```
belongs_to :breed
belongs_to :category
belongs_to :color
belongs_to :country
belongs_to :city
belongs_to :user
```

I collapse it to

```
[:breed, :category, :color, :country, :city, :user].each { |r| belongs_to r }
```

The question is:
Is it possible more collapse like

```
[:breed, :category, :color, :country, :city, :user].belongs_to
```

and how compose such code

or something like

```
[:breed, :category, :color, :country, :city, :user].each &:belongs_to
```

or something more elegant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still improve your solution with an [array of symbols](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Percent+Strings). But beside the fact I understand the will for elegancy and brevity, note that such a solution will prevent you from passing any option to your `belongs_to`... And there is no code smell in having multiple `belongs_to`

Comment: I find that reading diffs, stacktraces, etc are easier with multiple lines as well.

Comment: I agree with "multiple lines is not smell", but I reasoned that: added once and never works with "belongs_to" code takes more vertical space, I collapse it to single line and sort alphabetically to speed up visual finding. I watched a couple of seconds, undo changes, redo changes - and second version likes me more)